# How to Solution Repeat Data on newpage in rdf file

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

Example : Data Supplier Column this One Group
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AErHp.png

Next page : Repeat Data Same Picture 1
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3xCe.png

But In the case of two data items, first provide information same data in first picture before next data supplier.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpRN2.png

Comment: I'm confused - what is the topic now? SQL? RDF? And even the most confusing tag here is `word` - did you read the meaning of this tag?

Comment: So, what is your input data? To be honest, I didn't get the question given that you posted three images with some arabic data. Are you aware of grouping and window functions?

Answer (score 0):

That's an Oracle Reports (Builder) question (according to RDF, which is reports' file extension).

If that's so, then navigate to that field' Property Palette, scroll down to the "Advanced layout" section and check what's **Print object on** property set to - as far as I can tell, should be "All pages". Screenshots you posted suggest that it is now set to "First page".

Comment: I Create Template with word  and  Generated file output pdf But Data not repeat All pages. In fact, it can be done or not.